# Most idiomatic way to call fb() only if fa() succeeds

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I have two functions, I want to run `step_1`, then run `step_2` only if `step_1` was ok. Whats the most functionally idiomatic way to structure this code? Nesting `case` statements seems ugly but I'm not sure how else to do it besides an `if` which is even worse.

```
defmodule Test do
  def step_1 do
    IO.puts "Step 1"
    :error
  end

  def step_2 do
    IO.puts "Step 2"
    :ok
  end

  def do_something_case do
    case step_1 do
      :ok ->
        case step_2 do
          :ok -> {:ok}
          :error -> {:error, :step_2}
        end
      :error -> {:error, :step_1}
    end
  end

  def do_something_if do
    r1 = step_1
    if r1 == :ok
      r2 = step_2
      if r2 == :ok
        :ok
      else
        {:error, :step_2}
      end
    else
      {:error, :step_1}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this blog posting for further ideas: http://zohaib.me/railway-programming-pattern-in-elixir/

Comment: A proposal for this is now on the mailing list. I'll update my answer if/when this is implemented - https://gist.github.com/josevalim/8130b19eb62706e1ab37

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A common way to solve this problem (without a monad library) is to pattern match on the arguments of the functions and pipe them together.

```
defmodule Test do
  def step_1 do
    IO.puts "Step 1"
    :error
  end

  def step_2(:ok) do
    IO.puts "Step 2"
    :ok
  end
  def step_2({:error, _reason} = error) do
    error
  end

  def do_something_pipeline do
    step_1
    |> step_2
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, @gazler's solution or your solution using case are the best. The "if" should be avoided, as it is the hardest to read and understand by far in this particular case.